# Disable UAC win7 & Vista by VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, uac

I already build an Antivirus but the problem is When the windows start show the UAC message for Users, so that let them aware from it.
So how can I turn it off on bith windows Vista and win 7? or make my software as a secure software for Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UAC is a security feature. Your user may not be able to turn it off, so you need to design your application with UAC in mind.

Have a look at these links for some background information on how to program with UAC:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17968/Making-Your-Application-UAC-Aware

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/elevatedprivilegeuac

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16796/Riding-the-Vista-UAC-elevator-up-and-down